# To improve the speed of a windows application

Tags: c#, mysql, windows

I have created a windows application in which three main queries are executing when the application is loading. When I save some changes from it, again it is executing the three queries. So my application is getting slower. Three queries are independent to each other. What should i do to improve the performance of the application?

Comment: Please provide more information, posting in your queries would help

Comment: why not post your code on codereview

Comment: who knows what you should do? We know nothing about your application other than it contains some queries, which sometimes get executed. What do you mean by "getting slower", even? The queries take longer every time? How much data is there? How long do they take? Is one worse than the other? What do they look like? When _exactly_ are the executed? Have you checked your tables are properly indexed? Do you really need to execute them every time or you can you cache things, or return a subset of data? None of this we can know. Context is everything.

Comment: As a minimum, we need to see some code, but also a description of the environment, what tests you've done, table definitions, query definitions, explain plans would all be useful. Have you verified it's not a network issue? I think you need to do some basic debugging and monitoring before asking such a vague question. "It's a bit slow" is a user's description of the problem, not a programmer's. Technical details are required.

Comment: I will guess - try to execute each query in separate thread

Comment: Remove one of the queries.

Comment: @DanWilson lol why not just remove all of them? Then it'd be _really_ fast. The question says the queries are "independent", which I took to mean that they are unrelated to each other, and each is necessary for displaying some different pieces of data to the user. Perhaps that's not really the situation, in which your comment might actually be onto something :-). But the OP gave us pretty much zero info, so we can really only guess.

Comment: @Sasha I will to execute each query in separate thread.

Comment: @ADyson exactly. SO is not for guesswork. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you this very general answer:

1. Optimize the database structure (indexes)
2. Optimize queries:

   - optimize the amount of data to be retrieved (avoid: `select * FROM`)
   - Reduce the transaction level (avoid dead-locks)
   - Larger queries can be written in several ways. (join, subquery, temporay tables). In addition, consider splitting into several smaller queries.
3. Optimize the database server / buy more powerful
4. (Not recommended) Perform queries in parallel